# How can I use do edit-in-place on three different models from a View for a model those three belong_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-2, edit-in-place

I would like to enable edit-in-place functionality in a View that displays values from different models:

**This is what I use currently and it does NOT work, but would like some alternatives:**

I have a model called Campaign.  In the controller, I do the following to list, in order, the three Models that `belong_to` a Campaign:

```
<% @campaign_events = campaign_events %>
<% @campaign_events.each do |campaign_event| %>
    <% model_name = campaign_event.class.name.tableize.singularize %>
    <p>
        <%= link_to campaign_event.title,  send("#{model_name}_path", campaign_event) %>
        <span class='model_name'>(<%= model_name.capitalize %>)</span> 
        <%= campaign_event.days %> Days
    </p>
<% end %>
```

campaign_event is a `campaign_helper` defined as:

```
module CampaignsHelper
  def campaign_events
    return (@campaign.calls + @campaign.emails + @campaign.letters).sort{|a,b| a.days <=> b.days}
  end
end
```

I want to be able to click on the numerical value for Days when looking at the view/campaign/show and edit the value for `:days` (in this case, displayed as `campaign_event.days`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about it, but I'll try to help... I believe something like the following may work for you:

```
# calls controller
in_place_edit_for :call, :days

# emails controller
in_place_edit_for :email, :days

# letters controller
in_place_edit_for :letter, :days

# campaign view
<% @campaign_events = campaign_events %>
<% @campaign_events.each do |campaign_event| %>
   <% controller_name = campaign_event.class.name.tableize %>
   <% model_name = controller_name.singularize %>
   <p>
      <%= link_to campaign_event.title, 
         send("#{model_name}_path", campaign_event) %>

      <span class='model_name'>(<%= model_name.capitalize %>)</span> 

      <%= in_place_editor_field model_name, :days, {}, 
         :url => {
            :controller => controller_name, 
            :action => 'set_#{model_name}_title',
            :id => campaign_event.id} %> Days
   </p>
<% end %>
```

There's somethings I don't know exactly how to do:

1) `in_place_editor_field model_name`
I believe this won't work, but I don't know how to pass the model_name.

2) `:action => 'set_#{controller_name}_title'`
Not sure about it also. Just doesn't look right.

Anyway, hope it helps you... and forgive me if this is completely stupid.

Comment: thanks for the effort, it's not quite there...playing around with some of the ideas, though....